# Implementing image loading in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am in way of making a wallpaper app in android in which my first screen will be of categories then when I pressed each category it shows different images of small size but when I clicked on that particular image it shows the full screen image of that image ,I am implementing this in firebase storage ,so I want to ask how I will load same images of different sizes with same url??

Comment: use url parameters

Answer (score 0):

Add `Glide` Dependency in Your `Build.Gradle`

Use `Glide` To Load That Url

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("http://via.placeholder.com/300.png")
.override(100, 200) // resizes the image to 100x200 pixels but does not respect aspect ratio
.into(ivImg);
```

With `Aspect Ratio` in `Glide`

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("http://via.placeholder.com/300.png")
.override(100, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL) // resizes width to 100, preserves original height, does not respect aspect ratio
.into(ivImg);
```

More Information About Glide Follow This Link

https://github.com/bumptech/glide#download

Comment: Have You Got Your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look on picasso library

Picasso.load(url) .resize(50,50) .centerCrop() .into(imageView)

More information [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/)